# Grant Logon AS Batch using power shell script - Works fine if I ran it manually on windows server 2016 but fails when it is triggered from oneops

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

It creates tmp11.inf but its not exporting the user rights into tmp11.inf 0kb. Script fails at $currentConfig = Get-Content -Path $tempConfigFile since tmp11.inf is empty

1. I have added below line to ran as Admin but still same issue.

`Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "$('-File ""')$(Get-Location)$('\')$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)$('""')" -Verb runAs**`

````
2) OneOps execution both failed same issue,
   Method 1. ```powershell.exe -file E:\apps-packages\GrantLogonRights.ps1```
   Method 2. ```PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted','-File E:\apps-packages\GrantLogonRights.ps1' -Verb RunAs" ```

$username = "domain\account"

$rightBatch = "SeBatchLogonRight"

$tempConfigFile = "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp11.inf"

$tempDbFile = "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp11.sdb"

secedit /export /cfg $tempConfigFile /areas USER_RIGHTS 

$currentConfig = Get-Content -Path $tempConfigFile

$sid = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])).Value

    $newConfig = $currentConfig -replace "^$right .+", "`$0,*$sid"
    Set-Content -Path $tempConfigFile -Encoding ascii -Value $newConfig
    secedit /import /cfg $tempConfigFile /db $tempDbFile
    secedit /configure /db $tempDbFile /cfg $tempConfigFile /areas USER_RIGHTS
    gpupdate /force
````